# Glassfish: Error in linking security policy for

Tags: glassfish

I got an error while restarting or re-deploying an app to Glassfish and I get the exception below:

```
com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.CommandException: remote failure: Exception while loading the app : org.glassfish.deployment.common.DeploymentException: Error in linking security policy for appname -- Inconsistent Module State
```

What should i do to solve this issue?

Answer (score 12):

After googling for a couple of hours I found some replies and only this one worked for me:

Remove the application folder which is placed under **policy** folder:

```
rm -Rf /opt/sun-glassfish/glassfish/domains/domain1/generated/policy/appname
```

Then redeploy and restart Glassfish.

It should work.

Answer (score 0):

I also got same error when I try to start the payara server through eclipse, because **I added new user to admin realm by mistake.**

So, **I started the server from bin (startserv.bat) folder**, and **removed newly added user from admin realm**.

I started the server through eclipse and deployed the application.

It workrd for me.